# Read tweets using Twitter API v1.1 and jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, api, twitter, tweets

I have made a GET request to this URL to fetch my recent feeds.

Request:

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=**%23twitteruser**&result_type=recent&count=4
```

Result:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

My requirement is to show feeds using jQuery. So when I see this API I thought to use this using jQuery's Ajax.

Please help me how to authorize simply to read my own tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You should send your token info in the url as parameters such as: token, toke_secret and so on. You can also look at this web page: `https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth`